# Error reading words in the text file

Tags: asp.net, .net, string

I have been working on a code snippet today . A part of the Code reads the number of words in the file.I am using StreamReader to do the same , but it seems to give DirectoryNotFound Exception.Here is the code for the event

```
          protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = string.Empty;


    string FilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string[] Exe = { ".txt" };
        string FileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        bool isValidFile = Exe.Contains(FileExt);
        if (isValidFile)
        {
            int FileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            if (FileSize <= 102400)
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FilePath) + filename);

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FilePath+filename);
                //The error shows up here and i have tried to use FilePath as the single parameter too 

                int counter = 0;
                string delim = " ,.?!";
                string[] fields = null;
                string line = null;

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();//each time you read a line you should split it into the words
                    line.Trim();
                    fields = line.Split(delim.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    counter += fields.Length; //and just add how many of them there is


                }
                sr.Close();
                lblcount.Text = counter.ToString();





                lblMsg.Text = "File upload successfully!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "File Size allowed upto 100kb!";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Please Upload a text File!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Please upload a file!";
    }
}
```

}

Can this be sorted out ??

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build paths:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(FilePath), filename);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    // ...
}
```